# Select also records that are not paired in other table

Tags: sql-server, select

Couldn't find a better title... maybe I can explain better with some data

```
Table: persona        Table: AssPersona

Name       Number |   ID    food
----------------- |-----------------------
Giovanni      1   |   1     Ananas
Marco         2   |   2     Banana
Leonardo      3   |   4     ChocolateCoco
```

I would like to make a `SELECT` where I got all the `ID` from the table `AssPersona`

Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT persona.Name as Name, AssPersona.food As Food 
FROM AssPersona
INNER JOIN persona ON
persona.number = AssPersona.ID
GROUP BY Name
```

But the result I got is:

```
Name         Food     
---------------------------
Giovanni     Ananas
Marco        Banana
```

What I would like to obtain:

```
Name         Food     
---------------------------
Giovanni     Ananas
Marco        Banana
4            ChocolateCoco
```

Some tips?

Comment: [READ PLEASE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255517/should-we-be-afraid-to-ask-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if there is not guaranteed to be a record in `persona` then change to a `LEFT JOIN` as this will still return all results from `AssPersona` (which seems to be what is required).

Then use a `CASE` statement to determine whether the `Name` from the `peronsa` table is `NULL`.  If it is, return the `ID` field from `AssPersona`:

```
SELECT  CASE
          WHEN p.Name IS NULL THEN ap.ID
          ELSE p.Name
        END AS Name,
        ap.food AS Food 
FROM  AssPersona ap
LEFT JOIN persona p ON p.number = ap.ID
```